# SonarQube violation while deleting a cookie

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Here i tried to delete **JSESSIONID** Cookie

```
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", ""); // Getting SonarQube violation here
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie)
```

Then I am getting SonarQube vulnerability:

> Add the 'secure' attribute to this cookie

I tried to set the secure attribute by `cookie.setHttpOnly(true)`. But still I am getting this SonarQube issue. Can anyone help me with this?Is this false positive vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cookie.setSecure(true);